# Work done along a Spherical Gaussian surface

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

What will be the work done if a unit positive test charge is moved from one point to another along a Spherical Gaussian surface due to a point charge?
I'm guessing it will be zero as the Gaussian surface will be the same as equipotential surface due to a point charge (which is a sphere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep the work done will be zero. This can be stated because if there will be any potential difference then charges will move from low potential to high potential. Thus current will be generated without any external force, which is against law of conservation of Energy. Hence the surface have to be equipotential that is no work is done to move charge on spherical gaussian surface due to a point charge.